# Writing a function for UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I'm sick of writing basic UIAlertView's, ie:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWith...]] //etc
```

Instead of doing this, is it possible to put all this in a "helper" function, where I can return the buttonIndex, or whatever an alert usually returns?

For a simple helper function I guess you could feed parameters for the title, message, I'm not sure whether you can pass delegates in a parameter though, or bundle info.

In pseudo-code, it could be like this:

```
someValueOrObject = Print_Alert(Title="", Message="", Delegate="", Bundle="") // etc
```

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: This could be better tagged. Consider adding `objective-c`, `iphone`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I wrote, when I got sick of doing the same:

```
-(void)alert:(NSString *)title withBody:(NSString *)message firstButtonNamed:(NSString *)firstButtonName {
  [self alert: title withBody: message firstButtonNamed: firstButtonName withExtraButtons: nil informing: nil];
}

-(void)alert:(NSString *)title withBody:(NSString *)message firstButtonNamed:(NSString *)firstButtonName informing:(id)delegate {
  [self alert: title withBody: message firstButtonNamed: firstButtonName withExtraButtons: nil informing: delegate];
}

-(void)alert:(NSString *)title withBody:(NSString *)message firstButtonNamed:(NSString *)firstButtonName withExtraButtons:(NSArray *)otherButtonTitles informing:(id)delegate {
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
              initWithTitle: title
              message: message
              delegate: delegate
              cancelButtonTitle: firstButtonName
              otherButtonTitles: nil];
  if (otherButtonTitles != nil) {  
    for (int i = 0; i < [otherButtonTitles count]; i++) {
      [alert addButtonWithTitle: (NSString *)[otherButtonTitles objectAtIndex: i]];
    }
  }
  [alert show];
  [alert release];
}
```

You can't write a function that will display an alert and then return a value like a buttonIndex though, because that value-returning only occurs when the user presses a button and your delegate does something.

In other words, the process of asking a question with the `UIAlertView` is an asynchronous one.

Answer (score 14):

In 4.0+ you can simplify the alert code using blocks, a bit like this:

```
CCAlertView *alert = [[CCAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle:@"Test Alert"
    message:@"See if the thing works."];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Foo" block:^{ NSLog(@"Foo"); }];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Bar" block:^{ NSLog(@"Bar"); }];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel" block:NULL];
[alert show];
```

See [Lambda Alert on GitHub](http://github.com/zoul/Lambda-Alert).

Comment: Very slick solution. Worked great for me.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without using the `LambdaAlert` class?

Comment: You mean using the vanilla `UIAlertView` class? No. You would have to write some support code around it, which is exactly what `LambdaAlert` does. Why do you want to avoid it?